# when executing tuning-primer.sh with cygwin error occurs No valid socket file "/tmp/mysql.sock" found

Tags: mysql, performance, cygwin

Mysql performance tuning,
when i am executing tuning-primer.sh script on cygwin on windows os that type of error occurs.

No valid socket file "/tmp/mysql.sock" found!
The mysqld process is not running or it is installed in a custom location.
If you are sure mysqld is running, execute script in "prompt" mode or set
the socket= variable at the top of this. 
tuning-primer.sh script downloaded from https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer ,  after all i have run this script with prompt mode provide uid,pwd error is same.
any solution ?..
Note: Mysql server 5.6.14 is running on my computer. I have mysql.sock file in /var/lib/mysql/mysql.soc directory. I also link as /tmp/mysql.sock.

Comment: re-read your question and try to rephrase it in a more understandable way. In addition  are you expecting us to debug `mysql-tuning-primer` to catch witch command is providing the error message ? Error message should be reported as text not as image. Copy and past is easy in mintty.

Comment: I have rephrased my question. If any thing need to more understand able in question please let me inform.